# Html Helper methods are thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a Html helper method which internally calls Html.Action("action","controller"). I was worrying if this helper method is thread safe or there is any chance it'll mess up the output if the number of user's is going up into 10 K.

Note: sorry There was an issue when i was posting this question so the code was left.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString FormHelper(this HtmlHelper html, string id, TemplateField field, string retunUrl = "")
        {
            var fieldid = (new KeyValuePair<string, string>("template-field-id", field.Id));
            var editid = (new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data-edit-id", field.TemplateId.ToString()));
            var name =
                field.AttributesLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            var url =
                field.AttributesLists.FirstOrDefault(
                    x => x.Name.Equals("returnurl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (url != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url.Value))
            {
                // save return url in session
                retunUrl = url.Value;
            }
            return name == null ? new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty) : html.Action("WidgetsByZone", "Widget", new { widgetZone = name.Value, url = retunUrl });
        }
```

Comment: No, it won't mess up anything.

Comment: You're safe. besides, it's only being called within the worker thread; it's not like you're generating multiple pages in the same context.

Comment: `I have a Html helper method which internally calls Html.Action` Can you post that method? because *a method is thread-safe doesn't mean that code using it will be thread-safe*. Is that your method or I took you wrong?

Comment: The issue of thread-safety is moot here - the different requests are dealing with different contexts

Comment: Are you calling this method on the same instance `Html` from multiple threads? Or does each thread have it's on `HtmlHelper` instance (usually the case)?

Comment: Hi @SriramSakthivel this formHelper is called on a view and you can see the last line of the method is calling Html.Action("",""). I was talking in this context.

Comment: Hi @CodesInChaos That's the question is. I am calling the helper method in a view so it makes it in side 1 request 1 context. I am concerned about the html.Action("","") call inside it. if it is going to be thread safe or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft documents the thread safety of most of the classes they ship.

The following classes are all listed with the note:

> Any public **static** (**Shared** in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

- [`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx)
- [`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492619.aspx)
- [`System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.aspx)

Comment: How is that relevant? As I said in a comment to the (now deleted) answer by Jon, the method in question is not a member of any of those types. It's a member of `ChildActionExtensions`. And the thread-safety note on `ChildActionExtensions` doesn't say anything about its parameters, I think.

Comment: @svick Sure it does. If `ChildActionExtensions` only called static methods on `HtmlHelper`, why would it need an `HtmlHelper` instance as an argument? The only safe assumption is if instance methods are not necessarily thread safe, then neither are extension methods on that type.

Comment: So, you're saying that `Action()` is *not* thread-safe? Because that's not clear to me from your answer.

Comment: The MSDN documentation clearly states that [`ChildActionExtensions.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action.aspx) is not *necessarily* safe to call on multiple threads with the same `HtmlHelper` instance. If you have two different instances of `HtmlHelper`, you can use one on one thread and the second on another thread at the same time without problems.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not thread safe.

HtmlHelper has some instance properties, in particular ViewContext and ViewData (via ViewDataContainer) etc. Putting that anywhere static is a terrible terrible idea.

Comment: What does the non-guaranteed thread safety of these properties have to do with `Action`?

Comment: Thread-safety is directly related to the implementation of an operation. The documentation states they are thread-safe. Having instance properties does not mean they are not thread-safe. Those instance properties could be properly locked during modification.